# Any high-profile open source finance projects?

Tags: c#, open-source, finance

Is there a high profile open source project in the *finance* industry - specifically the investment banking area - that I could contribute to (ideally .NET)? I'd like to beef up my resume in this field.

I would prefer something in the algorithmic trading field, but am open to any route (e.g. front-office applications, etc).

Comment: Please be more specific- do you want to build mathematical models to determine how to trade, or build middle office tools to book trades, or something else?

Comment: Please consider voting for the quantitative finance stackexchange site idea here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5786/proposal-for-quantitative-finance-stackexchange-site.

Answer (score 8):

[QuantLib](http://quantlib.org/index.shtml)

[Mohawke's Best of the Best Free and Open Source Software Collection](http://www.digitaldarknet.net/thelist/) shows many finance open source projects, just "sort by type".

Answer (score 6):

[Finance AI on codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/financeAI)

FinanceAI is an open source project under the Ms-RL license with the goal of providing advanced Artificial Intelligence, Statistical and Mathematical tools for amateur and sophisticated investors. Once complete FinanceAI will be a complete algorithmic trading platform with comprehensive AI and Quantitative Finance libraries.

For a list of C# open source projects, check out [here](http://csharp-source.net/).

Answer (score 3):

I've not used it further than the demo but [Marketcetera](http://www.marketcetera.com/site/) are making a lot of noise recently. They offer a platform for automated strategy development through to execution and book keeping. From memory I think the technology is Java, ActiveMQ, Ruby on Rails.

Answer (score 2):

QLNet is port of the Quantlib library in C#.

Answer (score 1):

OpenAMQ - Messaging / Middleware

R - programming language used for stats

Answer (score 0):

(Not a high profile but growing organically healthy)

[JStock - Free Stock Market Software](http://jstock.sourceforge.net)

The above mentioned URL are more toward end users. If you are looking for developer related information, you may start to look at their [wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/jstock/).

Answer (score 0):

Open source FIX implementations - http://www.fixprotocol.org/

QuickFIX - http://www.quickfixengine.org/ and QuickFIX/J - http://www.quickfixj.org/

I've used QuickFIX/J in a production environment and it is quite stable and the codebase is easy to navigate and understand. In fact Marketcetera use QuickFIX/J for their fix engine.

Answer (score 0):

There is a research project that might interest you: http://www-rocq.inria.fr/mathfi/Premia/index.html.

Answer (score -3):

There is an eclipse open finance market platform

Most financial companies don't like open source as they are afraid of the licensing issues when modifying software.